# Modificar EditText de RecyclerView desde fuera (del RecyclerView)

Tags: recyclerview

Podría alguien darme alguna solución u orientarme con esto:

Estoy implementando un RecyclerView (con un LinearLayoutManager) que muestra una lista con dos, tres o cuatro EditText, en cada fila, según el DataSet que cargue (solo puede ser una de las tres opciones en cada carga).

Todos los EditText están deshabilitados (no permiten introducir texto) desde el ViewHolder.

Pero no puedo conseguir que, mediante ToggleButton's (fuera del RecyclerView), poder habilitar/deshabilitar los EditText's de las columnas del RecyclerView. Es un botón

Los EditText están creados en un array de EditText's en el ViewHolder para más tarde acceder sus setEnable según un índice del array (como si fueran columnas).

Lo más cerca que estuve de conseguirlo fue usando un método estático del Adapter para habilitar/deshabilitar los EditText. El método lo llamaba desde un Activity usando también el notifyItemRangeChanged() del Adapter, pero ese método solo se puede usar una vez si no se le entrega como parámetro un Object payload. Y hasta ahí llegué, no investigué más porque me ha tomado mucho tiempo.

Aguien sabe la manera correcta de conseguir esto? (lograr modificar, desde fuera del RecyclerView, las propiedades de los View que carga). U orientarme sobre qué probar.

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente solucioné el problema volviendo a establecer el Adapter en el RecyclerView. No usé `notifyItemRangeChanged()` ni otro método.

Lo que hice para **modificar** la propiedad `isEnable` de mis **EditText's** fue:

- Establecer, en el Adapter, **variables booleanas públicas estáticas**
  para cada columna (de EditText's) y un **método público estático** para
  modificarlas desde fuera del Adapter.

Las **variables booleanas** las uso para establecer el true o false para los isEnable's de los EditText's en el constructor del ViewHolder del Adapter.

Luego, cuando hago uso del **método** desde fuera del Adapter, también vuelvo a establecer el adaptador `recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptador)` para que se produzcan correctamente los cambios en los EditText's.